# react - how to make the value of a variable remain unchanged when the component re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is how my App looks.

App.js

```
const Home = () => {
  const [inputValues, setInputValues] = useState(...);

  const word = generateRandomWord(); // how to make the word not changing 

  return (...)
```

generateRandowWord.js

```
export const generateRandomWord = () => {
  // return a random word in string
}
```

Every time `inputValues` changes, the `Home` component will be re-render, and the value of `word` is different too. How can make the value of `word` remain unchanged?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `useMemo` hook:

```
const word = useMemo(() => generateRandomWord(), []);
```

The word will be regenerated when a value in the dependencies array has changed. If you pass an empty array the value will always stay the same between rerenders.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider to store the result in a state so you can change it later if you need

```
const Home = () => {
  const [inputValues, setInputValues] = useState(...);

  const [word, updateWord] = useState(generateRandomWord()); 

  return (...)
```

Comment: Will the value of `word ` change after re-rendering?